Formatting view in C# ASP.NET Core
I have a little problem with button setting on view. I want to keep button "Complete" right next to "SearchButton". "Complete" button has to send selected checkbox (ID) to the action method Complete.
In full code, how can I do that ?
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <form id="mainForm" asp-controller="Structures" asp-action="Index" method="get" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="SearchString" class="sr-only">Type Order number</label>
            Order number: <input type="text" name="SearchString" class="form-control ml-2" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="All" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-14">
                <form id="completeForm" asp-controller="Structures" asp-action="Complete" method="post">
                    <div class="tab d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="openCity(event, 'Inventory')">Inventory</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <button id="selectAllYellow" class="btn btn-primary">Type Yellow</button>
                            <button id="selectAllGreen" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Type Green</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table id="dataTable" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Main</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Check</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.OrderList)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="Main">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Main)</td>>
                                    <td class="Quantity">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
                                    <td class="Status">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.Status)</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="@item.ID" type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.ID" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I was trying to do it this way, but it didn't send any Id to the Complete action method.
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <form id="mainForm" asp-controller="Structures" asp-action="Index" method="get" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="SearchString" class="sr-only">Type Order number</label>
            Order number: <input type="text" name="SearchString" class="form-control ml-2" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Search</button>
    </form>

    <form id="completeForm" asp-controller="Structures" asp-action="Complete" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml-2" value="Kompletacja" />
    </form>
</div>


"I was trying to do it this way, but it didn't send any Id to Complete action." - the checkboxes aren't contained in the form you are submitting there any more, so of course it doesn't send them. But you can use the form attribute to specify with form an input element belongs to, even if it is not actually contained within the form.

I got it. Didn't know that i can make it this way. Thanks you.     
